# Using ggplotly on a ggplot2 graph does not work with boxplot variable width or outliers shape change

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot

When I use ggplotly on a ggplot2 graph, some features of ggplot2 are reset.

Code example:

```
library(tidyverse)
db <- iris

# Changing the N in one of the categories for the example:
db$Sepal.Length[1:40] <- NA

p <- db %>% ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)

p
```

[image: Picture 1]

When using *ggplotly(p)* the varwidth option does not work, and the outlier shape of a circle returns. Is this an inherent quality of ggplolty? If so, how do I get these options in ggplotl2?

[image: Picture 2]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. A reproducible example would be great, this helps us help you. did you mean `ggplot()`? does the same happen when using an inbuilt data set, such as `iris`? If yes, could you update your question based on such a data set? e.g. `iris %>% ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA) `

Comment: See my answer below - it at least helps for the outlier bit. To be honest, I don't think it helps the visualisation to set `var.width = TRUE` - it may be clearer to actually show the values, e.g. with `geom_jitter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly does not seem to inherit all ggplot arguments indeed. At least the outliers can be changed following this thread:  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1114

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
p <- iris %>% ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() 

# Need to modify the plotly object and make outlier points have opacity equal to 0
p <- plotly_build(p)

for(i in 1:length(p$x$data)) {
  p$x$data[[i]]$marker$opacity = 0
}

p
```

Outliers are removed. I am not sure if it is possible to inlcude `var.width` into plotly boxplots.

**I am not sure though if `var.width` actually helps visualisation** - many people including myself are not very good in comparing the width of bars  ... In order to compare the sample size, it may be clearer to actually show the values, e.g. with `geom_jitter`:

```
p <- db %>% ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]